# Показ контента, который не вмещается в блок при наведении

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такая структура блоков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать, что бы при наведении по бокам контейнера с контентом выдвигался и показывал скрытый блок, отодвигаясь в сторону?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Без кода сложно дать конкретный ответ, например можно так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  border: 3px solid gold;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

.col-1:hover {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.col-1:hover+.col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1">Содержимое1</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Содержимое2</div>
  <div class="col col-3">Содержимое3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как быть, если это слайдер slick и в нем используется центрирование? На мобильном разрешении показываются элементы навигации и работает как обычный слайдер

Comment: Приложите ваш пример кода, что конкретно вы хотите? Что и почему не получается? Со стороны, никаких проблем не видно, писать с нуля вряд ли вам тут будут. Нужен исходник.